# nginx auth_basic stopped working

Tags: nginx, http-authentication

I had defined basic auth for nginx like this:

```
auth_basic "Login to access";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/httppwd;
```

It used to work fine until today when it stopped working without any change being made. It simply does not allow https acess anymore.
I checked the self-signed cert and it is still valid.

I changed the `username:password` in `/etc/nginx/httppwd` and restarted but it still refuses any connection.

When I disable auth lines, it resumes working.

I checked whether my desktop IP address is blocked by `iptables -s '1.2.3.4'` but it not in the blocked list.

So I'm wondering what could be wrong here and how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and replace "stopped working" with the actual symptoms or error message you saw, and the precise steps that previously worked.

Comment: I bet the answer lies in the **error.log**

Comment: Does it affect all users and all browsers?